# Package keyval error when compiling bibliography (Package keyval Error: given_i undefined. \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc])

Tags: graphics, bibliographies, miktex, key-value

I'm quite new to LaTeX. I had MiKTeX 2.9.5987 and I use TeXstudio as editor to write a thesis. I had no errors in my `.tex` file for long, but due to missing/messing `graphicx` package (I wanted figures arrays) I decided to uninstall MiKTeX and install the new version 2.9.6069. I also uninstalled TeXstudio and re-installed it after installing MiKTeX 2.9.6069, loading my previous TeXstudio profile.
For some reason, though, I am unable to build the pdf as I get this errors (on the same line):

```
Package keyval Error: given_i undefined. \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
Package keyval Error: family_i undefined. \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

I'm unable to find this errors description anywhere: what are they related to? How can I fix this?

The code I'm using is a slightly modified version of Steve R. Gunn, Sunil Patel and Vel's master/doctoral thesis:

```
\documentclass[
% (skipped font and page setting)
]{MastersDoctoralThesis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib} 
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}    
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mparhack}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}

% (skipped irrelevant lines)

\begin{document}

\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
\include{Chapters/Chapter2} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
\include{Chapters/Chapter4} 
\include{Chapters/Chapter5}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc] %line where error is located

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome! Try removing generated files concerned with the bibliography e.g. `.bcf`, `.bbl` etc. and recompile.

Comment: Note that we cannot reproduce the error without a (Non-)Working Minimal Example. The code you've given is not something anybody but you can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What we really need, still, is a link to this documentclass, `MastersDoctoralThesis.cls`, and some actual content in place of your `\include`d files (which, presumably, no one else in the world has). I also wonder if you could reproduce the problem still by replacing `\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}` with `\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}` (which comes with the `biblatex` package) and adding, say, a `\cite{knuth:ct}`?

Comment: Thank you very, VERY much, it worked! In my various attempts I only tried to delete the .bbl file and not the .bcf and .toc: now it works nicely. I'm very sorry, next time I'll be more thorough with the code...!

Thank you very much to jon, too

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was fixed by deleting the `.bcf` and `.toc` files.